# Angular DataTable not populating DTInstance

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am not getting my DtInstance populated after rendering. Anyone faced this issue.

```
<div ng-controller="InventoryTableController as vm">
          <table datatable="" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" dt-columns="vm.dtColumns"
                 dt-instance="vm.dtInstance"
                 class="display table table-bordered table-striped table-hover"></table>
      </div>
```

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: Thanks Alger for looking into this, I was able to fix it by vm.dtInstance = null;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix it by this https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/365

The problem was due to I initialized the dataHolder like this

```
vm.dtInstance = {};
```

It fixed when I changed it into `vm.dtInstance = null;`
even `vm.dtInstance = undefined` wont work.

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer so future visitors can see that this is a reliable solution.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding my 2 cents here.

For me the problem was solved by @rosshays solution in the thread: https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/345

**Update Dec. 4 2017:**
As per @trainoasis suggestion, i am copying the solution to here.

> In your controller

```
$scope.nested = {};
$scope.nested.dtInstance = {}
```

> And in your HTML

```
<table
    datatable=""
    class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed"
    dt-options="dtOptions"
    dt-columns=dtColumns
    dt-instance="nested.dtInstance">
</table>
```

Comment: This worked for me too when no other answer did. I suggest you add some info on how to achieve this in the answer beside the link, since it doesn't take much ... will be more helpful if the link dies ..

Answer (score 3):

For me even vm.dtInstance = null; did not work.
I ended up going throught the source of the directive and found that dt-instance can also be a setter function. That solved the problem for me.

```
vm.setDTInstance = function(dtInst){
    vm.myTable = dtInst;
};
```

Comment: And you added dt-instance="vm.setDTInstance" or what? and thats it? Before doing that your dtInstance was undefined? And what is myTable in your case? I'm using Angular datatables so I did not define a table at all ...

Answer (score 2):

I am using

```
.withOption('serverSide', true).withFnServerData(getDataFromServer)
```

and I was having the same issue, but it was resolved with the following code:

**Controller**

```
$scope.dtInstance = {};
$scope.dtIntanceCallback = function (instance) {
    $scope.dtInstance = instance;
}
$scope.dtRebind = function () {
    $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.draw()
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table datatable dt-instance="dtInstanceCallback"></table>
<button ng-click="dtRebind">Rebind</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to trigger this is to iterate over a sequence of tables, using `<... ng-repeat="table in tables"> <table datatables="ng" dt-instance="dtInstance" ... >`. When there is more than one table, it is not surprising that this way, `dtInstance` may not refer to the table that you expected it to.

However, when you know that there is always exactly one table in the set, you might expect `dtInstance` to refer to that one instance. But it does not. The solution in my case was to get rid of the extra layer and simply use the one table.