# Add a checkbox in each row for datatable jQuery using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox, datatables

I want to display some data in a `datatable` format by using Angular.js.

So I did something like below.

**Angular**

```js
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-datatables.js"></script>

var app = angular.module('myapp', ['datatables']);
app.controller('homectrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'dtoptionsbuilder', 'dtcolumnbuilder',
    function ($scope, $http, dtoptionsbuilder, dtcolumnbuilder) {
        $scope.dtcolumns = [
            //dtcolumnbuilder.newcolumn("action", "action"),
            dtcolumnbuilder.newcolumn("objectid", "id"),
            dtcolumnbuilder.newcolumn("service_code", "service code"),
            dtcolumnbuilder.newcolumn("cond1", "condition 1"),
            dtcolumnbuilder.newcolumn("cond2", "condition 2"),
            dtcolumnbuilder.newcolumn("cond3", "condition 3"),
            dtcolumnbuilder.newcolumn("service_type", "service type"),
            dtcolumnbuilder.newcolumn("remark", "remark"),
            dtcolumnbuilder.newcolumn("description", "description")
        ]
        $scope.dtoptions = dtoptionsbuilder.newoptions().withoption('ajax', {
            url: "/home/getdata",
            type: "post"
        })
        .withpaginationtype('full_numbers')
        .withdisplaylength(10);
    }])
```

```html
<div ng-app="MyApp" class="container" ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
        <table id="entry-grid" datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-hover">           
        </table>
<br />
    </div>
```

And **Controller**

```
public ActionResult getdata()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnAPP_NEIQC"].ToString()))
        {   
            GetData objGetData = new GetData();
            dt =  objGetData.GetDataForGrid();

            var circleList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                           select new 
                           {         
                               //Action = "",
                               OBJECTID = Convert.ToString(dr["OBJECTID"]),
                               SERVICE_CODE = Convert.ToString(dr["SERVICE_CODE"]),
                               COND1 = Convert.ToString(dr["COND1"]),
                               COND2 = Convert.ToString(dr["COND2"]),
                               COND3 = Convert.ToString(dr["COND3"]),
                               SERVICE_TYPE = Convert.ToString(dr["SERVICE_TYPE"]),
                               REMARK = Convert.ToString(dr["REMARK"]),
                               DESCRIPTION = Convert.ToString(dr["DESCRIPTION"]),
                           }).ToList();

            return Json(circleList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Now what I want is, I want to add a `CHECKBOX` in each row so that I can edit and update its record.

Comment: Do you want to add new rows and post or edit existing rows with checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by yujinpan you can use the select extension. Or simply just render out a checkbox yourself:

```
$scope.dtcolumns = [
  dtcolumnbuilder.newcolumn(null, '').renderWith(function(data, type, full)
     return '<input type="checkbox" class="check" data-object-id="'+full.objectid+'">'
  }),
  dtcolumnbuilder.newcolumn("objectid", "id"),
  ...
]
```

Now you can associate delegated event handlers with the checkboxes through the `.check` class.

---

Use a `dtInstance` as explained [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33980618/1407478) or in the docs [**here**](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/api) (look at the bottom of page). Now you could do something like

```
$('#entry-grid').on('click', '.check', function() {
   var data = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.row($(this).closest('tr')).data()
})
```

Comment: I got the checkbox as needed. Now, how to add title and oncheck of checkbox to get the current row data ?? any idea sir. Thanks for your useful answer

Comment: Nothing in alert for `alert(data);` ?? how to check values are coming properly

Comment: also getting error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined`

Comment: @BN, have you used a callback to set the `dtInstance`? Use the last example in the linked SO thread -> **https://stackoverflow.com/a/50624700/1407478**

Comment: tried like this `$scope.dtInstance = {};` but still not working. same error. also added in `table` like this `<table id="entry-grid" datatable="" dtinstance="dtInstance" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-hover"></table>`

Comment: @BN, As said, use a callback as demonstrated in the linked-to answer.

Comment: yes, that's working now with another small issue, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined`

Comment: You have `dtinstance` instead of `dt-instance` (or `dtInstance`) ...?

Answer (score 1):

Is it this one？the select plugin.
[withSelect](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/withSelect)

Comment: yes this one.. but its not getting selected. and also what If I want to select all at once ??

Comment: Yes, look at this..[rowSelect](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/rowSelect)