# On Checkbox check always getting the first row value in the alert using angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable

I have a `datatable` with many records in it. And each row consists of checkbox. What happening here is, at any row I check for alert *I am always getting the data of the first row of the datatable.*

Below is my code.

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['datatables']);
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder',
    function ($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
        $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null, '').renderWith(function (data, type, full) {
                return '<input type="checkbox" class="check" data-object-id="' + full.objectid + '">'
            }),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("OBJECTID", "ID"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("SERVICE_CODE", "Service Code"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("COND1", "Condition 1"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("COND2", "Condition 2"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("COND3", "Condition 3"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("SERVICE_TYPE", "Service type"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("REMARK", "Remark"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("DESCRIPTION", "Description")
        ]
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
            url: "/home/getdata",
            type: "POST"
        })
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        .withDisplayLength(10);

        $scope.dtInstance = {};
        $scope.dtInstanceCallback = function (instance) {
            $scope.dtInstance = instance;
        }
        $scope.dtRebind = function () {
            $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.draw()
        }

        $('#entry-grid').on('click', '.check', function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var data = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.row().data();
            var strStringifyData = JSON.stringify(data);

            alert(strStringifyData);  //here its coming

        })
    }])
```

Please suggest how to implement it

Comment: On your click handler you are getting `var row` but it is not used anymore. You need to get value from this particular row, ` var data = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.row(row).data();`

Comment: Try to get correct row using row() method https://datatables.net/reference/api/row()

Comment: @dganenco: I am using it, have a look here `var data = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.row().data();`

Comment: ok, any idea on how to do single selection at a time. I am now able to select multiple rows

Comment: Try to get selected row using '.selected' selector. I'm trying to prepare fiddle for you. `$scope.dtInstance.DataTable.row('.selected').data()`

Comment: ok. i will try too by the time

Comment: `('.selected')` is not working.. getting undefined

Comment: Because you were not listening carefully to the previous answer :) No offense! You should do `var data = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.row(row).data();` if `row` is `var row = $(this).closest("tr");` or simply `var data = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.row($(this).closest('tr')).data()` as in the [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54196981/1407478)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it. You can use [node as selector for row.](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector) So in your particulr case

```
var selectedRow;
$('#entry-grid').on('click', '.check', function () {
                                if(selectedRow){
                    $(selectedRow).find('.check').prop('checked', false);                
                }

                            selectedRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0]
                var data = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.row(selectedRow).data();
                var strStringifyData = JSON.stringify(data);

                alert(strStringifyData);  //here its coming

            })
```

Comment: i am still able to select multiple rows at a time. can we make it single ??

Comment: Is it possible to using 'sRowSelect' : 'single' feature. You need to add it on your initialization phase https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/initialisation

By default when row selection is active, TableTools will select a row when any element in the table is clicked. It can be useful to limit this selection to certain columns, or even certain elements in the row, which can be done through this option. It is a simple jQuery selector string that is used to select the elements that will perform the select..

Comment: I updated my answer. Internal implementation will not satisfy your requirements I guess.

Comment: yes, its working now. can I ask u one more thing if you don't mind ?

Comment: Sure, we are here especially for that

Comment: what I want is, whenever I check on any checkbox, a pop up should open or the row should become editable for updating records which will update in database.. ? can you help me with that.. if you have any link also please share with me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186781/discussion-between-dganenco-and-b-n).

Comment: @BN, do not over complicate, it is redundant to the insane to include a "`selectedRow`". You already had it in the answer yesterday, you just simply forget to include `row` in `$scope.dtInstance.DataTable.row(row).data()` ...Obvious you can do as you wish, but I foresee a lot of problems if you are polluting your code with redundant nothing burgers ...

Comment: @dganenco: what happen mate, are u busy today ??

Comment: @davidkonrad: what was that ?

Comment: @BN, sorry, mispost, copy/paste, something completely different ;)